# three.js pyramid height inconsistency

Tags: three.js

i am looking to create multiple pyramids that have different heights but need some clarification on why this is not working.

when i only change the height of the second pyramid, the bottom radius looks smaller and the position of the pyramid also changes in the scene.

if both are set to 0,0,0 -- why are they in different locations?

if both have the same top radius and bottom radius, why is one wider than the other?

[image: pyramids]

```
<script> 

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = 3;

var pyramidgeo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0,1,1,4,false);
var pyramidmat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe:true, color:0xFFDE14});
var pyramid = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeo,pyramidmat);
pyramid.position.set(0.0,0,0);
pyramid.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(pyramid);

var pyramidgeo1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0,1,2,4,false);    
var pyramid1 = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeo1,pyramidmat);
pyramid1.position.set(0,0,0);
pyramid1.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(pyramid1);

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
render();

</script>
```

Comment: BTW, `CylinderGeometry`'s fifth arg is a number, not a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gero3/f88Vj/5/

shows that one isn't wider then the other

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = 3;

var pyramidgeo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0,1,1,4,false);
var pyramidmat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe:true, color:0xFFDE14});
var pyramid = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeo,pyramidmat);
pyramid.position.set(0.0,0,0);
pyramid.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(pyramid);

var pyramidgeo1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0,1,2,4,false);    
var pyramid1 = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeo1,pyramidmat);
pyramid1.position.set(0,0,0);
pyramid1.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(pyramid1);

var lineGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.707,2,0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.707,-2,0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.707,2,0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.707,-2,0.707));

lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.707,2,-0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.707,-2,-0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.707,2,-0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.707,-2,-0.707));

lineGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeo,new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 1 } ),THREE.LinePieces)
scene.add(line);



function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
render();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gero3/f88Vj/6/

shows they are in the same location and 2 small one go into a large one

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = 3;

var pyramidgeo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0,1,1,4,false);
var pyramidmat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe:true, color:0xFFDE14});
var pyramid = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeo,pyramidmat);
pyramid.position.set(0.0,0,0);
pyramid.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(pyramid);

var pyramidgeo1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0,1,2,4,false);    
var pyramid1 = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeo1,pyramidmat);
pyramid1.position.set(0,0,0);
pyramid1.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(pyramid1);
/*
var lineGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.707,2,0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.707,-2,0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.707,2,0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.707,-2,0.707));

lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.707,2,-0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.707,-2,-0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.707,2,-0.707));
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.707,-2,-0.707));

lineGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeo,new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 1 } ),THREE.LinePieces)
scene.add(line);*/

var pyramidgeo1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0,1,1,4,false);
var pyramidmat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe:true, color: Math.random() * 0xffffff});
var pyramid1 = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeo1,pyramidmat1);
pyramid1.position.set(0.0,0.5,0);
pyramid1.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(pyramid1);

var pyramidgeo2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0,1,1,4,false);
var pyramidmat2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe:true, color: Math.random() * 0xffffff});
var pyramid2 = new THREE.Mesh(pyramidgeo2,pyramidmat2);
pyramid2.position.set(0.0,-0.5,0);
pyramid2.rotation.y = Math.PI/4;
scene.add(pyramid2);

var SphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1,10,10);
var MeshBasicMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(SphereGeometry,MeshBasicMaterial);
sphere.position.set(0,0,0);
scene.add(sphere);



function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
render();
```

The changes you see in width and height are due to the perpective camera.